# second form showing at same time as first form

Tags: php, mysql

The php file I am working on is for returning members. The preceding htm module has links for returning members and new members.  The returning link sends the member to the returning php module.

The first form asks for member number and password.  The module finds the members row in the database (which you helped me with the other day).  The second form is supposed to be populated with the data from the members record and allow the member to update his record.

The problem is that the second form shows up right away before the first form requested data is entered.

I would like to prevent the second form from showing up prematurly.  I have tried to find the answer but again, I am probably not asking the right question.

Does anyone have a quick answer with this info or should I put my code on the question?  If I need to submit code how much should I put out here.  It's fairly lengthy.  I am hoping one or more of you know the common mistakes that cause this.  The forms have different names.  I read a lot on my searches and the previous statement is the only thing that I saw that could have been the problem.

Thanks in advance.
oldmanvette

Comment: have you tried `if` statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Name two forms submit button differently. You can differentiate these 2 form when submitting two form

Also use a session mechanism  if you are authenticated user ,and then only you have to show the second form

Sample

```
Login Form resides here <form name=login ..... </from>

When authenticated save a session with user details .See      http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

if(session set) {
  //Show the user details form 
  User details page
  <form name=deails. ..... </form>
}
```

Comment: Thanks @duke. I'm going to see if the submit button is all I need to change first and if needed I will get into the session mechanism. I googled "session mechanism in php" and low and behold it led me to stackoverflow.  I'll be back with a progress report as soon as I check out these tips.